Strange error happens when I try to install the package
When I try to install a package, a following error is displayed.


Error (SingleRecordQuery_NoRecords): No record found for SELECT
AppExchangeDescription,AppExchangeLogoUrl,AppExchangePackageName,AppExchangePublisherName,BuildNumber,CspTrustedSites,Dependencies,Description,Id,InstallValidationStatus,IsBeta,IsDeprecated,IsManaged,IsOrgDependent,IsPasswordProtected,IsSecurityReviewed,MajorVersion,MinorVersion,Name,Package2ContainerOptions,PatchVersion,PostInstallUrl,Profiles,PublisherName,ReleaseNotesUrl,ReleaseState,RemoteSiteSettings,SubscriberPackageId
FROM SubscriberPackageVersion WHERE Id = '04t----------'


Looks like this is another temporary issue with a newly created package version being not available for installation.
In 10-20 minutes another error pops up but this error is not reproduced any more.
Per Salesforce Support message, this was one time error, which might have been fixed by data fixer. They refused to open a known issue or publish a knowledge article since this error happened only once and is not likely to reoccur in the future, and if this error reoccurs they suggested to email them directly.
